# Flutter app crash after converting Provider 3 to 4

Tags: flutter

I tried to upgrade my Flutter app to use `Provider 4.0.1` today and the following code crashed on assigning a value to null.

Here is the code I am attempting to convert. I only changed `SingleChildCloneableWidget` to `SingleChildStatelessWidget` which compiled OK.

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/single_child_widget.dart';

List<SingleChildStatelessWidget> providers = [
  ...independentServices,
  ...dependentServices,
  ...uiConsumableProviders
];

List<SingleChildStatelessWidget> independentServices = [
  Provider.value(value: Api()),
  Provider.value(value: Tbl()),
  Provider.value(value: Bill()),
  Provider.value(value: Sale()),
  Provider.value(value: Category()),
  Provider.value(value: Menu()),
];

List<SingleChildStatelessWidget> dependentServices = [
  ProxyProvider<Api, AuthenticationService>(
    update: (context, api, authenticationService) => AuthenticationService(api: api),
  ),
];

List<SingleChildStatelessWidget> uiConsumableProviders = [
  StreamProvider<User>(
    create: (context) => Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false).user,
  ),
    lazy: false
];
```

I implemented it like this:

```
StreamController<User> _userController = StreamController<User>();
Stream<User> get user => _userController.stream;
```

The crash occurred at this line:

```
Future<void> _setFixedLanguageStrings(BuildContext context) async {

 User _user = Provider.of<User>(context);
 
 _user.homeString = await translate(context, 'Home');
```

> The getter 'language' was called on null. Receiver: null

This was working fine with `Provider 3.0.3` but obviously I need to do more.

My original code came from  [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-provider-v3-architecture-using-proxyprovider-for-injection-62cf5c58ea52).

edit: I fixed that problem by adding `lazy: false` in the stream provider create method but then another error later in this code.

```
Future<String> translate(BuildContext context, _term) async {

  final String _languageCode = Provider.of<User>(context).language;
```

which produced this error:

> Exception has occurred.
> _AssertionError ('package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 213 pos 7: 'context.owner.debugBuilding || listen ==
> false || _debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate': Tried to listen to a
> value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.
>
> This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed)
> that called Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
>
> To fix, write: Provider.of(context, listen: false);
>
> It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget
> associated to the event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care
> about the value. )

I added `listen: false` to the line above which seems to have fixed that problem, however the next provider I attempted to use produced this error:

> Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the
> widget tree.
>
> This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed)
> that called Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
>
> To fix, write: Provider.of(context, listen: false);
>
> It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget
> associated to the event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care
> about the value. 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 213 pos 7: 'context.owner.debugBuilding || listen ==
> false || _debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate'

Should I now go to every instance where I call a provider and add `listen: false`? I need somebody to explain what has changed and why as I am fairly new at Flutter and the docs are sparse for `Provider`. There are many times where I call Provider in my code and this last error did not return a code location.

Is `listen: false` now always required when it wasn't before or have I missed something else? I am starting to add listen: false to every call to instantiate a Provider variable and it appears to be working but is this the correct approach? Should I just add `listen: false` to every call to `Provider.of` and call it a day?

edit: The error arises whenever the provider is called from outside the visible part of the widget tree. This distinction is important.

Comment: Got the same problem when updating. Thing is, what if I may or may not change the widget tree? I'm rolling back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same "problem", if i add `listen: false` everywhere i call Provider the problem is gone but i dont know if thats the right solution...?

Comment: I wonder why `listen: false` isn't the default for `SingleChildStatelessWidget`?

Comment: there is no error with listen: false, but UI does not update, so something else needed to make it working

Comment: reason being that they will not listen for any update changes, instead are responsible for making changes

Answer (score 11):

On Event Handlers like *onPressed*, *OnTap*, *onLongPressed* etc. we must use

```
Provider.of<T>(context,listen:false)
```

reason being that they will not listen for any update changes, instead are responsible for making changes.

whereas widgets like Text etc. are responsible for displaying...hence need to be updated on every change made....therefore use

```
Provider.of<T>(context,listen:true)  //by default is listen:true
```

Answer (score 7):

`listen:true` being the default is logical.

It's not specifying inside an event handler that is not logical.`listen: false`

Also, 4.1.0 will somehow have a shorter alternative to Provider.of:

```
context.read<T>() // Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false)
context.watch<T>() // Provider.of<T>(context)
```

Comment: Thenks for your help

Comment: Can you point me the documentation link of these.

Answer (score 3):

`listen : false` called when the data wouldn't updating any thing in the UI, and should be used, like removing all cards in a widget when button clicked.

For more info's, read this [go_to_link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#providerof)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was getting the following error:-

```
I/flutter ( 7206): Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.
I/flutter ( 7206): 
I/flutter ( 7206): This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
I/flutter ( 7206): Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.
I/flutter ( 7206): 
I/flutter ( 7206): To fix, write:
I/flutter ( 7206): Provider.of<AstroDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false);
I/flutter ( 7206): 
I/flutter ( 7206): It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
I/flutter ( 7206): event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.
```

As you can see that solution is present in the error message itself.

Hence, we are not supposed to use provider with default (listen:true) inside event handlers.

Alternatively,

````
context.read<T>() is same as Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false) And
context.watch<T>() is same as Provider.of<T>(context)```

Ref :- https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/313
````

Answer (score 2):

If you are using provider outside the build without ***listen: false***

then, of course, you can't listen to changes as it didn't build the widgets again for changes. this doesn't come as a default value because the provider is **not supposed to use outside the build as it used as a state management tool and to inject dependencies.**
But however, if you are using outside the build you have to use **listen: false**

Answer (score 2):

If we use,

```
 Provider.of<T>(context, listen: true).method();
```

inside build method and if we have

```
 notifyListeners();
```

in that method(), then it causes infinite recursion , as on each

```
 notifyListeners();
```

invoke ,all provider calls with listen : true will execute , i.e build method is re executed, that means

```
 method(),
```

is called again and again and result in error

Comment: then what if we want the UI updated? getting error if I added the listen: true, but need update to ui also. :(